# Is it possible to schedule the Dataprep same job to treat different data sources according to time?

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

I have some data sources coming from different countries that are loaded at different time in some GCP buckets due to timezone differences.
All the sources have the same schema so they can be treated with the same job.

I would really like to keep a unique job so to centralize fixes and changes to recipes.

Is it possible to schedule a dataprep job, so that according to the time uses different time sources (maybe using variable parameters)?

For example schedule the same job at 12 pm to treat only sources from UK, at 8 am only sources from US and at 4 pm only sources from NZ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create multiple schedules for the same output right now.

You can however create a reference dataset from your recipe and add it to several flows.

You need first to create a reference dataset:
[image: Create reference dataset]

You can then insert that reference dataset in several flows. Each flow can then have its own schedule, output settings or variables but the logic is reused.
[image: Using a reference dataset in a flow]

Comment: Hi Hughes, thanks for your reply. Still this way the recipe is not unique any more. That means that when I want to make some changes to the recipe, I have to do it in each flow. With the increase of the number of the data sources, this becomes time-consuming and prone to errors.